# Angular get http requests are not sent with HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, keycloak

I have the following keycloak configuration in my angular application :

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { KeycloakOnLoad, KeycloakPkceMethod } from 'keycloak-js';
import { KeyCloakProperty } from '@core/properties/keycloak/keyCloak.property';
import { excludedUrls } from '@core/constants/excluded-urls.constant';

export function loadConfigFactory(keycloak: KeycloakService, keyCloakProperty: KeyCloakProperty) {

  return () => keyCloakProperty.getKeyCloakConfigPromise()
    .then(async (kcProperty) => {
      await keycloak.init({
        config: kcProperty.config,
        initOptions: {
          onLoad: kcProperty.options.onLoad as KeycloakOnLoad,
          pkceMethod: kcProperty.options.pkceMethod as KeycloakPkceMethod
        },
        bearerExcludedUrls: excludedUrls
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err) });
}
```

===============================

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { loadConfigFactory } from '@core/factories/config/load-config.factory';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { KeyCloakProperty } from '@core/properties/keycloak/keyCloak.property';
import { ApiInterceptor } from '@core/interceptors/api-interceptor/api.interceptor';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from '@core/interceptors/error-interceptor/error.interceptor';
import { SpinnerOverlayInterceptor } from '@core/interceptors/spinner-overlay/spinner-overlay.interceptor';


registerLocaleData(localeFr);

function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfigFactory,
      deps: [KeycloakService, KeyCloakProperty],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ApiInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: SpinnerOverlayInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

this configuration works when using chrome browser while it doesn't work (http requests are not sent using HttpClient) on Edge and Firfox until I remove this section

```
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfigFactory,
      deps: [KeycloakService, KeyCloakProperty],
      multi: true
    }
```

I put some console.log at the interceptors level, no logs is displayed on the browser console
no errors displayed as well